# Add a coded UI recording as test case in test manager

Tags: coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I have a coded UI project and i have done the hard way of creating recording via code completely avoiding recording part.

Now what i want to do is to use this recording as test case created in windows test manager

Is it possible , if so can anyone pls help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the recorded test method used when executing the test via MTM, you'll have to associate the automation with the test case TFS work item.  This is done by opening the work item, clicking on the "Associated Automation" tab, navigating to the test solution's dll, and then selecting the appropriate test method from the drop down list.  At that time, you'll see the "Automation Status" field of the test case change from Not Automated or Planned to Automated.  When you save the work item and go back to your test plan, assuming you've set up your test environment correctly (VS Test Controller, VS Test Agents), you should be able to right click on the test and select "Run" to have the MS Test engine run through your code.

I wrote a more detailed description of it [here](http://notfarragut.blogspot.com/2014/01/from-test-case-to-automation.html) (complete with pretty screen shots).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I used tcm.exe to import all test cases to tfs and now all are visible in mtm :) anyway thanks Ryan Cox

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes it a lot easier to associate automation across an entire test suite.  Good find!